# How do i prove this language is regular?

Tags: regular-languages, finite-automata, closure-properties

I have this language {0+1+0+} and i need to prove it is regular,i had the idea to use the closure properties but i can find any regular languages to unify perhaps.Any ideas?

Comment: What about the concatenation of $0^+ = 00^*$ with $1^+ = 11^*$ with $0^+ = 00^*$?

Comment: Good one,i did not know that 0+ or 1+ was regular.

Answer (score 0):

Build a finite state machine. Or look up the definition, your definition will either say "there's a finite state machine", or "it's defined by a regular expression".